# NSDate differs with different timezones in iOS

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nscalendar, nstimezone

I have a calendar app, in which I highlight current date,

I have followed the following steps, at present my device time is 11:59 am,

Indian time zone, I change it to first 9.am, then I change time zone to san jose ,

I get time as 25th june 9.34 pm, now in device calendar it shows 25th june, but

in my app it still shows 26th june.

I am getting current date this way

```
-(void)initialize
{
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    [gregorian setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
    NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSDayCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit  | NSMinuteCalendarUnit)fromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSInteger day    = [weekdayComponents day];
    NSInteger month  = [weekdayComponents month]; 
    NSInteger year   = [weekdayComponents year];

   [m_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];

    m_dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";

    NSDateComponents *timeZoneComps=[[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [timeZoneComps setDay:day];
    [timeZoneComps setMonth:month];
    [timeZoneComps setYear:year];
    [timeZoneComps setHour:00];
    [timeZoneComps setMinute:00];
    [timeZoneComps setSecond:01];

    m_currentDate         = [gregorian dateFromComponents:timeZoneComps];   

}
```

So, I need your help in this regard.

Comment: Because you are explicitly using `UTC` time zone?

Comment: I removed it , now for san jose it works fine and in my app, it shows 25th june, but now if I change time zone to australia which is ahead of indian time zone, it should show me 26th june, but it shows 25th june. Why can that problem be due to?

Comment: Hello @trojanfoe, can you please have  a look at my comment

Answer (score 0):

I think that `[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]` will always give you the current timezone as detected (or set) by the device. Since the timezone is cached in your app you can also call `[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone]` to make sure that the info is up to date. So, in your code:

`[NSTimeZone resetSystemTimeZone];
[m_dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];`

Comment: Hey @spassas as I have created my calendar by setting timezone to UTC, I cant change that now, bcoz it will break few things, is there something we can do, keeping time zone as UTC.

Comment: Umm, I'm not sure I follow. You are trying to get the current date in the current timezone, is that correct? So you cannot explicitly use `UTC` timezone... If I may ask, what is it you're afraid of breaking?

Comment: I have used UTC time zone for my previous versions of the app. So now if I use system time zone then I will get different time. so now the previous dates will be in UTC and the new dates will be in systemtime zone so the time differs

Comment: I don't see how that would cause problems. Just retrieve the current timezone, get the day/month in the timezone and highlight the appropriate cell in your app. Why would that break any previous versions?

Comment: I will try it out and get back to you.

Comment: Hello @spassas, I will explain my problem clearly, user can select dates from calendar and I am saving it in plist , Now my current calendar is made from UTC, so whenever I select a date I assign to it time 00:00:01 so when I save it to plist it will show me for example 2-jul-2014, 5:30:01, So all dates are in same way. Now suddenly if I change to current time zone, now the new dates which user will save will not have 5:30:01 as time stamp and will save the current time, so when I retrieve whether their will be issues?